# How Django links to item detail page at admin site?

Tags: python, django

I met a problem when learning Django Tutorial. I design a `detail` method in `views.py` to show detailed information for each item I added in pdf-format and a admin page. The problem is, when I'm on the **admin web page** editing a particular item, how to add a hyperlink pointing to **its corresponding** `detail` web page?

I construct my urls in this way:

```
urlpatterns = [..., url(r'^(?P<item_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail')]
```

To do that, I need to get that **item id** at the corresponding template. It seems that `change_form.html` is the template and the overwritten function `render_change_form` inside `MyModelAdmin` class is the function who renders the template. So, is it possible to get the item id in `render_change_form`? I noticed that there is a question asking this, yet there is no accepted answer.
So is getting item id the correct way solving it? What's the proper solution to do that?

Comment: are you trying to change in the admin? or in the front of yourr website??

Comment: In the admin. I wanna add a hyperlink in the admin, which points to the item's corresponding `detail` web page

Comment: but in admin on the list page the items which are available on click on one it goes to the details page only

Comment: I mean, I design my own detail function which generates a report for the item. I wanna add a link linking to that report. It's different from just clicking the item on the item list at admin site.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the [`get_absolute_url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) method.

Example :

```
from django.urls import reverse

class Foo(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

Now a "View on site" button appeared at the top right (when you see a single item if the admin).

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.view_on_site) more information about Django admin and `get_absolute_url()`.